# How do you replace a '|' with ' ' or null string?

Tags: python

I removed all the null values and numbers from my data. I only have list of lists containing text strings and '|'. I want to loop over my RDD object and replace the '|' with '' or even remove it.

I tried using the map function and then I linked it to an external function

```
def fun(item):
    newlist=list()
    for i in item:
        if '|' == i or '|' in i:
            j=''
            newlist.append(j)
        else:
            newlist.append(i)
    return newlist

final=orginial.map(x : fun(x))
```

---

```
input: [['Hello','|'],..]

expected output: [['Hello',''],..]

actual output: [['Hello','|'],..]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `replace` in python.

```
a = "ABCD|EFG"
a = a.replace("|", "")
```

i change the code you can use this:

```
def fun(item):
    newlist=list()
    for i in item:
        newlist.append(i.replace("|",""))
    return newlist
```

if you want to get rid of the empty strings you could also try this

```
output = []

for single_list in list_of_lists:
    new_in_list = [i for i in single_list if not i is "|"]
    output.append(new_in_list)
```

i add more example :

```
a = ["hello|||", "he||oagain", "|this is |", "how many ||||||||| ?"]
output = []
for i in a:
    output.append(i.replace("|", ""))
print(output)
```

at the end output is :

```
['hello', 'heoagain', 'this is ', 'how many  ?']
```

Comment: In my data, I have 4 to 5 values that contain " | ". I just need to find them and change them into " " values. Do you have any idea for that?

Comment: @RahulKiran i add more example for you,  you can use `replace` for any values.